# Connection problems between Asp.Net Core Api and Asp.Net Webapp with Angular

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api with asp.net core and an Asp.Net core webapp in which communication between them is not happening.

I did the api tests with Postman and everything worked fine, but when it's the web application this error is being returned:
**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:15741/api/Home/CalculaEmprestimo' from origin 'http://localhost:39903' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

I configured CORS on the web api but the error still persists.

API

```
  public class Startup
  {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
      Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddCors(options =>
      {
        options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                          builder =>
                          {
                            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:39903");
                          });
      });

      services.AddControllers();
      services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
      {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebAPI", Version = "v1" });
      });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WebAPI v1"));
      }

      app.UseRouting();
      app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

      app.UseAuthorization();

      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
      });
    }
  }
```

Angular Service

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IEmprestimo } from '../Model/emprestimo.interface';
import { IEmprestimoResult } from '../Model/emprestimoresult.interface';
import { fromEvent, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { strict } from 'assert';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmprestimoService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  postEmprestimo(pEmprestimo: IEmprestimo): Observable<IEmprestimoResult>
  {
    const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Connection':'keep-alive' };
    const body = {
                    "parcelas": pEmprestimo.parcelas,
                    "valorParcelas": pEmprestimo.valorParcelas,
                    "valorEmprestimo": ""
                  };

    var result = this.http.post<IEmprestimoResult>('http://localhost:15741/api/Home/CalculaEmprestimo', body);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me resolve this?

Comment: If you try to write http://localhost:39903 without a trailing slash in your ConfigureServices - does that make any difference?

Comment: I removed the slash from the end, but the error is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure to include AllowAnyHeader() and AllowAnyMethod() before WithOrigins("...")
2. If you're using Angular and you didn't change default port then you should rather use WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
3. Sometimes you need to enable Cors on some browsers, try to run on multiple browsers and check if the problem persists.

Comment: Here is an example of how to enable Cors on the Web API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api